# Youtube Red audio stops for downloaded videos

Tags: audio, video, youtube, webm, opus

I am uploading videos to Youtube, and on my Android phone I am downloading them using Youtube Red. I am playing these downloaded videos in the background, when the screen is off.
This works with the wast majority of the videos, except the ones that I am uploading.
I did read the recommended upload formats, I tried several codecs, but no luck. My audios stop the second I am shutting off the screen.

What I finally found using `youtube-dl -F` is that my videos do not have audio-only tracks with webm extension, only as m4a (after Youtube processed them).
So my question is: what makes Youtube create webm audio files for some videos, but not for the others? Is there a way to force this (I suppose not). Is there a way to suggest it? As I mentioned, I tried a wide variety of codecs - video and audio, and the combinations - when generating my files to be uplaoded.

A sample output for a file which works:

```
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only DASH audio   52k , opus @ 50k, 73.58KiB
250          webm       audio only DASH audio   66k , opus @ 70k, 92.62KiB
251          webm       audio only DASH audio  114k , opus @160k, 161.14KiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  115k , vorbis@128k, 161.27KiB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  127k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k, 180.79KiB
```

and the output for one file which does not:

```
format code  extension  resolution note
139          m4a        audio only DASH audio   49k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.5@ 48k (22050Hz), 1.20MiB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  129k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 3.20MiB
```

Comment: Ask at [**`SuperUser.com`**](https://superuser.com). Did you try converting your file to webm first before uploading to Youtube?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion - partially - with the following command:

    ffmpeg -i Timeline1.mov -c:v copy -c:a libopus Timeline1.mkv
This copies the video stream as is, but converts the audio to Opus.
It seems that Youtube does not really care about that, it converts immediately , after the upload:

    format code  extension  resolution note
    139          m4a        audio only DASH audio   55k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.5@ 48k (22050Hz), 59.96KiB
    140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  156k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 157.14KiB